# Calculating the 95th percentile: Comparing normal distribution, R Quantile, and Excel approaches

Tags: r, dataset, quantiles, sql

I was trying to compute the 95th percentile on the following dataset. I came across a few online references of doing it.

#### Approach 1: Based on sample data

The [first one](http://answerpot.com/showthread.php?2694010) tells me to obtain the `TOP 95 Percent` of the dataset and then choose the `MIN` or `AVG` of the resultant set. Doing so for the following dataset gives me:

```
AVG: 29162
MIN: 0
```

#### Approach 2: Assume Normal Distribution

The [second one](https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=118781) says that the 95th percentile is approximately two standard deviations above the mean (which I understand) and I performed:

```
AVG(Column) + STDEV(Column)*1.65: 67128.542697973
```

#### Approach 3: R Quantile

I used `R` to obtain the 95th percentile:

```
> quantile(data$V1, 0.95)
79515.2
```

#### Approach 4: Excel's Approach

Finally, I came across [this](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2009/09/fun-with-percentiles-part-1.html) one, that explains how Excel does it. The summary of the method is as follows:

Given a set of `N` ordered values `{v[1], v[2], ...}` and a requirement to calculate the `pth` percentile, do the following:

- Calculate `l = p(N-1) + 1`
- Split `l` into integer and decimal components i.e. `l = k + d`
- Compute the required value as `V = v[k] + d(v[k+1] - v[k])`

This method gives me `79515.2`

None of the values match though I trust R's value is the correct one (I observed it from the ecdf plot as well). My goal is to compute the 95th percentile manually (using only `AVG` and `STDEV` functions) from a given dataset and am not really sure what is going here. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
93150
93116
93096
93085
92923
92823
92745
92150
91785
91775
91775
91735
91727
91633
91616
91604
91587
91579
91488
91427
91398
91339
91338
91290
91268
91084
91072
90909
86164
85372
83835
83428
81372
81281
81238
81195
81131
81030
81011
80730
80721
80682
80666
80585
80565
80534
80497
80464
80374
80226
80223
80178
80178
80147
80137
80111
80048
80027
79948
79902
79818
79785
79752
79675
79651
79620
79586
79535
79491
79388
79277
79269
79254
79194
79191
79180
79170
79162
79154
79142
79129
79090
79062
79039
79011
78981
78979
78936
78923
78913
78829
78809
78742
78735
78725
78618
78606
78577
78527
78509
78491
78448
78289
78284
78277
78238
78171
78156
77998
77998
77978
77956
77925
77848
77846
77759
77729
77695
77677
77382
70473
70449
69886
69767
69704
69573
69479
69398
69328
69311
69265
69178
69162
69104
69100
69072
69062
68971
68944
68929
68924
68904
68879
68877
68799
68755
68726
68666
68623
68588
68547
68458
68457
68453
68438
68438
68429
68426
68394
68374
68363
68357
68337
68300
68256
68250
68228
68216
68180
68149
68124
68114
68060
68029
68029
68025
68004
67996
67981
67964
67938
67925
67914
67901
67853
67819
67818
67788
67770
67767
67688
67670
67669
67629
67618
67609
67602
67583
67540
67479
67475
67470
67433
67420
67387
67343
67339
67337
67315
67273
67224
67208
67160
67137
67102
67045
66449
66408
66338
66211
63784
63557
63091
63021
62895
62663
62182
62079
62044
61907
61888
61856
61847
61792
61764
61683
61641
61612
61514
61511
61503
61411
61263
61248
60965
60941
60907
60876
60773
60669
60537
60525
60387
60194
59673
59576
59561
59556
57652
57458
57308
57264
57158
57106
56288
56245
56054
56031
55930
55841
55533
55532
55316
55281
55230
55196
55111
55101
50957
50870
49580
48353
21349
21319
21288
21274
21270
21255
21232
21208
21196
21184
21164
21150
21149
21143
21129
21108
21100
21072
21043
20934
20912
20908
20882
20871
20858
20843
20839
20834
20800
20790
20788
20757
20752
20748
20744
20739
20721
20712
20710
20671
20620
20575
20572
20567
20551
20536
20522
20510
20484
20430
20415
20398
20368
20362
20357
20349
20347
20341
20338
20335
20335
20334
20332
20332
20332
20330
20326
20324
20323
20307
20304
20299
20297
20292
20282
20280
20275
20270
20270
20258
20257
20257
20256
20254
20252
20251
20247
20243
20231
20229
20223
20223
20221
20219
20217
20215
20212
20211
20210
20208
20202
20202
20202
20197
20192
20190
20190
20187
20186
20184
20179
20175
20175
20170
20170
20170
20166
20162
20158
20157
20157
20156
20153
20152
20151
20151
20148
20146
20141
20141
20139
20137
20133
20132
20130
20129
20124
20124
20123
20114
20109
20104
20104
20094
20092
20091
20088
20086
20085
20084
20083
20078
20076
20076
20070
20068
20065
20060
20052
20049
20045
20041
20040
20039
20037
20036
20036
20032
20032
20021
20020
20017
20009
20007
20007
20004
20004
20002
19989
19985
19974
19973
19973
19967
19961
19960
19959
19957
19953
19952
19950
19943
19942
19940
19940
19939
19937
19936
19935
19935
19925
19921
19920
19914
19908
19907
19900
19900
19900
19899
19899
19898
19898
19894
19893
19891
19891
19888
19888
19888
19883
19883
19882
19882
19880
19878
19875
19875
19874
19873
19871
19867
19864
19862
19861
19860
19857
19856
19854
19854
19848
19848
19844
19842
19840
19840
19835
19833
19831
19830
19828
19826
19820
19817
19812
19812
19811
19809
19805
19799
19792
19789
19788
19785
19780
19770
19765
19763
19762
19754
19743
19742
19738
19737
19735
19731
19724
19722
19721
19711
19710
19699
19698
19697
19695
19692
19687
19683
19672
19670
19665
19664
19660
19654
19651
19644
19643
19643
19641
19640
19620
19619
19618
19617
19614
19613
19608
19607
19607
19605
19579
19575
19568
19556
19553
19553
19551
19550
19548
19536
19535
19500
19500
19473
19462
19461
19455
19451
19391
19388
19386
19384
19375
19371
19353
19338
19318
19273
19271
19269
19265
19258
19230
19228
19222
19221
19221
19215
19196
19180
19177
19166
19161
19154
19148
19138
19134
19129
19116
19113
19107
19105
19102
19096
19092
19088
19085
19085
19083
19072
19067
19066
19061
19058
19050
19049
19045
19044
19043
19043
19032
19005
18996
18968
18957
18948
18938
18936
18920
18920
18913
18897
18897
18892
18884
18878
18878
18878
18871
18870
18869
18866
18864
18864
18864
18862
18862
18862
18860
18859
18858
18858
18853
18852
18852
18851
18851
18848
18847
18846
18846
18846
18845
18845
18844
18842
18841
18841
18840
18840
18837
18837
18836
18836
18835
18834
18833
18831
18830
18830
18829
18829
18829
18828
18826
18825
18823
18822
18822
18822
18821
18821
18821
18819
18819
18818
18816
18813
18812
18812
18812
18812
18810
18809
18809
18809
18809
18808
18808
18806
18805
18805
18804
18803
18802
18802
18801
18801
18801
18801
18800
18799
18799
18798
18797
18796
18796
18796
18795
18795
18793
18792
18792
18792
18791
18791
18791
18789
18789
18789
18788
18787
18783
18782
18782
18782
18781
18781
18780
18780
18779
18779
18779
18779
18778
18777
18777
18776
18775
18773
18773
18772
18772
18771
18770
18770
18770
18769
18769
18767
18767
18766
18762
18762
18761
18761
18761
18758
18757
18757
18756
18756
18755
18751
18750
18749
18749
18749
18746
18746
18746
18746
18746
18745
18745
18744
18744
18743
18742
18739
18739
18738
18737
18736
18734
18729
18729
18727
18727
18723
18723
18723
18723
18721
18721
18721
18719
18719
18719
18719
18718
18717
18716
18714
18710
18710
18710
18708
18707
18704
18702
18701
18701
18699
18695
18694
18692
18691
18690
18689
18689
18686
18684
18683
18681
18679
18675
18675
18672
18665
18665
18665
18658
18656
18655
18654
18654
18654
18652
18650
18649
18646
18645
18642
18640
18638
18638
18636
18633
18633
18631
18630
18629
18625
18625
18623
18622
18619
18617
18617
18616
18616
18614
18614
18614
18614
18611
18611
18609
18609
18600
18597
18596
18594
18593
18591
18589
18585
18580
18578
18578
18578
18572
18569
18567
18566
18565
18563
18559
18559
18557
18557
18554
18551
18548
18547
18545
18544
18544
18541
18539
18539
18536
18535
18531
18529
18526
18524
18524
18522
18517
18515
18503
18502
18497
18496
18496
18496
18495
18493
18492
18487
18487
18486
18486
18485
18482
18479
18473
18471
18470
18464
18463
18460
18459
18454
18454
18452
18450
18447
18446
18442
18442
18442
18440
18439
18434
18432
18427
18426
18425
18421
18416
18414
18408
18407
18407
18407
18403
18402
18398
18397
18396
18394
18393
18392
18391
18390
18383
18378
18357
18356
18354
18349
18342
18341
18338
18337
18336
18333
18328
18319
18314
18313
18302
18295
18295
18291
18291
18288
18284
18281
18278
18276
18272
18269
18268
18263
18262
18261
18259
18257
18251
18247
18240
18240
18238
18235
18235
18234
18232
18225
18222
18221
18214
18214
18213
18213
18210
18210
18206
18205
18204
18203
18194
18192
18191
18190
18187
18184
18179
18179
18179
18175
18171
18170
18156
18152
18151
18151
18149
18149
18148
18148
18147
18146
18140
18139
18137
18137
18136
18135
18135
18134
18133
18133
18128
18128
18127
18127
18125
18122
18121
18120
18120
18119
18117
18110
18108
18108
18099
18097
18096
18096
18095
18087
18085
18084
18083
18067
18060
18056
18056
18054
18053
18050
18049
18048
18038
18036
18033
18033
18028
18027
18025
18023
18022
18010
18010
18010
18000
17995
17983
17980
17978
17975
17974
17974
17968
17968
17967
17965
17964
17962
17961
17956
17955
17943
17938
17935
17934
17933
17932
17930
17925
17923
17919
17912
17912
17904
17897
17896
17894
17884
17880
17874
17872
17870
17865
17857
17856
17854
17854
17845
17843
17841
17836
17834
17831
17831
17828
17822
17821
17821
17816
17804
17803
17799
17798
17794
17794
17793
17790
17787
17786
17783
17782
17781
17777
17777
17777
17772
17772
17771
17766
17766
17758
17750
17747
17743
17715
17699
17694
17683
17682
17681
17668
17668
17630
17619
17617
17610
17609
17609
17607
17607
17599
17587
17565
17551
17542
17532
17531
17514
17514
17512
17509
17503
17483
17481
17475
17465
17463
17449
17433
17404
17397
17356
17356
17214
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: You first approach needs to be rewritten: it could be "take the top 5% of values and find the minimum of them", in this case 79586, or "take the bottom 95% and find the maximum of them", in this case 79535.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first approach is completely wrong and has nothing to do with the 95th percentile, in my opinion.

The second approach seems to be based on an assumption that the data is normally distributed, but it should be about 1.645 standard deviations above the mean, not 2 standard deviations, and it looks like you realised this. This is a poor method if the data is not normally distributed.

If you want to work out the 95th percentile yourself, order the numbers from smallest to largest and find a value such that 95% of the data is below that value. R probably uses some sort of interpolation between data points. A simple approximation might be `sort(data$V1)[0.95*length(data$V1)]`.

Edited after comment from @Macro.

Comment: your solution would require `data$V1` to be pre-sorted. More generally, `sort(data$V1)[.95*length(data$V1)]`, would be the approximation you want. However, if `.95*length(data$V1)` is not an integer it would just round down to the nearest integer when indexing `sort(data$V1)`, so this approximation would always underestimate in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I knew about the underestimation, which is why I called it a simple approximation, but I forgot to include the sorting. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 18):

Here are a few points to supplement @mark999's answer.

- [Wikipedia has an article on percentiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) where it is noted that no standard definition of a percentile exists. However, several formulas are discussed.
- Crawford, J.; Garthwaite, P. & Slick, D. On percentile norms in neuropsychology: Proposed reporting standards and methods for quantifying the uncertainty over the percentile ranks of test scores The Clinical Neuropsychologist, Psychology Press, 2009, 23, 1173-1195 ([FREE PDF](http://www.abdn.ac.uk/~psy086/dept/pdfs/PREprints/ClinicalNeuropsychologist_Percentiles_Reporting_Standards_Uncertainty_PREPRINT.pdf)) discusses calculation of percentiles within a psychology norming context.

The following explores a few things in R:

#### Get data and examine R quantile function

```
>  x <- c(93150, 93116, 93096, etc... [ABBREVIATED INPUT]
> help(quantile) # Note the 9 quantile algorithms
> rquantileest <- sapply(1:9, function(TYPE) quantile(x, .95, type=TYPE)) 
> rquantileest
     95%      95%      95%      95%      95%      95% 
79535.00 79535.00 79535.00 79524.00 79547.75 79570.70 
     95%      95%      95% 
79526.20 79555.40 79553.49 
> sapply(rquantileest, function(X) mean(x <= X))
      95%       95%       95%       95%       95% 
0.9501859 0.9501859 0.9501859 0.9494424 0.9501859 
      95%       95%       95%       95% 
0.9501859 0.9494424 0.9501859 0.9501859
```

- `help(quantile)` shows that R has nine different quantile estimation algorithms.
- The other output shows the estimated value for the 9 algorithms and the proportion of the data that is less than or equal to the estimated value (i.e., all values are close to 95%).

#### Compare with assuming normal distribution

```
> # Estimate of the 95th percentile if the data was normally distributed
> qnormest <- qnorm(.95, mean(x), sd(x))
> qnormest
[1] 67076.4
> mean(x <= qnormest)
[1] 0.8401487
```

- A very different value is estimated for the 95th percentile of a normal distribution based on the sample mean and standard deviation.
- The value estimated is around the 84th percentile of the sample data.
- The plot below shows that the data is clearly not normally distributed, and thus estimates based on assuming normality are going to be a long way off.

  > plot(density(x))

[image]

Comment: has provided a very nice answer. I would only add that it seems to me that in most cases, the differences among the 9 estimates are so small as to matter very little.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [quantiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) is better than the one on percentiles

Comment: Something is wrong here as R should be giving numbers between 75500 and 75600. Did some of the 1345 values get lost?

Comment: @Henry thanks for that. In my attempt to minimise the number of lines displayed for input on the question, I placed the c(...) command on only a couple of lines. As a result I think I encountered some form of command line length limit which was chopping off some of the data. I'd never seen this issue before because usually I'd have such data in a separate file. I've updated my script and the output so that the c(...) command now spans 120 lines; see gist https://gist.github.com/1102127

Comment: +1 Thank you the additional information. Just when you posted this, out of curiosity I was looking at the distribution using a QQ-plot and reached the same conclusion. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I see that you noticed my change (addition of Excel's method). Would you have any comments on the method? There seems to be a paper (http://www.coventry.ac.uk/ec/~nhunt/pottel.pdf) that reveals some flaws in Excel's method but so far, the values that R gives me are matching with that of Excel.