# Correct use of statement including the word percentile

Tags: terminology, quantiles

If Billy was to say that:

> I completed my second year of college above the 95th percentile.

Does that mean that if there are 200 people in Billy's year, he appeared in the top 10 students?

I cannot get whether this is correct from Wikipedia. Also if it is not correct, if Billy was to appear in the top ten at his college, what would be the correct statement?

Answer (score 1):

In principle the answer is yes but there is no real consensus about how to estimate the centiles from a sample as indicated in detail in this [Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13399/calculating-the-95th-percentile-comparing-normal-distribution-r-quantile-and?rq=1) where both answers are well worth reading.